# "The project doesn't know hot to run the profile MauiApp.WinUI"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, preview, winui-3, maui, .net-6.0

I am trying to get started with a brand new .NET Maui application. Upon creating the project, it has a single project for the MauiApp, and another project named MauiApp.WinUI. When I try to run the the app on my Windows 10 device, I get the error: "The project doesn't know hot to run the profile MauiApp.WinUI". I am not sure what to do in order to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: which exact version of vs you are using?

Comment: I used Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview (16.11.0 Preview 2.0) to get the Maui templates to appear. That is the version I used when this issue occurred as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case installing [Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftSingleProjectMSIXPackagingTools) solved the problem.

Just in case, I already had [Project Reunion (Preview)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftProjectReunionPreview) installed.

Comment: it works for me too, but why we need these extensions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I moved the links inline to aid in readability. Please review the markup so you can add links to your answers in the future.

Comment: Also, I used the same URLs you had defined, but the first URL doesn't actually point to a tutorial, but simply references the _Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools_ referenced by the second link. Can you correct that URL?

Comment: I have updated the link of "Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools for VS 2022 preview" package.

Comment: @ChinmayT - the question is tagged [tag:visual-studio-2019] though.  Better to add the link rather than replace it -- but it's already there anyway in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69782249/3744182) of [Shidouuu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14555957/shidouuu).

Answer (score 14):

As of 7/14/21, you should use the [Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools for VS 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftSingleProjectMSIXPackagingToolsDev17), not the one for VS 2019.

Comment: Why is this still in preview as of Aug 2022? VS 2022 has been out for over 6 months...

Answer (score 4):

I was under the impression after watching a few of the community hangouts that all you needed to do was run the maui-check tool.

It appears that there are other dependencies beyond the tools capabilites, or that it doesn't check, which is a little annoying. But are listeed in the [installation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation).

[Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftSingleProjectMSIXPackagingTools)

[Project Reunion (Preview)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftProjectReunionPreview)

After installing these everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

From VS 2022 preview : I just deleted the file launchSettings.json and the app launched !

Answer (score 0):

I installed Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools extension and Project Reunion extension (preview for VS2022). But this was not enough, I still could not start the app.

Then I installed [MSIX Packaging tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/msix-packaging-tool/9n5lw3jbcxkf?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from MS Store, and it finally worked.

Here's my `launchSettings.json` file:,

```
"profiles": {
    "TestWinUI": {
      "commandName": "MsixPackage"
    }
  }
```