# WinUI 3 Template in Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.5

Tags: winui-3

The default application created using the template **Blank App, Packaged with Windows Packaging Project (WinUI 3 in Desktop)** in VS 2022 executes by setting the Package project as the startup project. (With the WinUI project as the startup project "`'Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll'`" error was thrown.)

However the application created with **Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)** shows following error on execution:

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure you have installed the [required workloads and components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480198/2411960)?

Comment: Yes I do have the required workloads, components and SDK installed:
Workload: .NET Desktop Development
SDK: Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
Components: Windows App SDK C# Templates, MSIX packaging tools, Single-project MSIX packaging tools for VS 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the lines of resolution for a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050253/the-project-doesnt-know-hot-to-run-the-profile-mauiapp-winui) found with .Net MAUI application, installing [Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools for VS 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftSingleProjectMSIXPackagingToolsDev17) solved the problem for me.

In fact this is documented in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/winui-project-templates-in-visual-studio#blank-app-packaged-winui-3-in-desktop) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue in VS 2022.

I suggest you could follow the Doc: [Install tools for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b), to set up your development computer.

Comment: Yes I do have the required workloads, components and SDK installed:
Workload: .NET Desktop Development
SDK: Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
Components: Windows App SDK C# Templates, MSIX packaging tools, Single-project MSIX packaging tools for VS 2022.

Comment: I suggest you could try to `Repair` the visual studio.